# Is there anyway to check the past logs in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I write a log function for one functionality, seems the logs message only for 24 hours, after that I couldn't see it.

Is there anyway to check the logs for past days in drupal?

Comment: Under "Reports" -> "Recent log messages" you can see logs and they are NOT limited to 24 hours. Or..if you are talking about your custom log function then how can we know why it's logging only 24h when we don't know anything about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're finding limitations with database logging, you might want to try enabling the core Syslog module (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/syslog/overview), which will send Drupal logs to your operating system's syslog file (e.g. /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog) or a custom log file.